# how to override username method i want to pass 2 value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

hello guys i m try to override auth function to create login form in which 
user can login with email id or phone number so i m try to override inbuilt auth here is location vendor\laravel\framework\src\foundation\auth\authenticatesuser.php

here is code i want to override $username
i want to  pass two variable in $username  like 'phone' and 'email' using "or" condition   how i can achieve this

```
 public function  loginUsername()
  {
    return property_exists( $this,'username') ? $username : 'phone';

  }
```

is this a best way to edit ? or any other way in which i can achieve all functionality provide by auth in laravel 5.2

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to edit that method but you must override it instead.

```
public function loginUsername()
{
    $loginUsernames = ['username', 'email', 'phone'];

    foreach ($loginUsernames as $loginUsername) {
        if (property_exists($this, $loginUsername)) {
            return $loginUsername;
        }
    }

    throw new \Exception('Unknown user type!');
}
```

Comment: its throwing error  Unknown user type i had given correct credential